# Xcode Build Phase - Run Script. How to define a variable in a scheme to read at build phase script?

Tags: xcode, shell, xcode6

I've created a new scheme, and I want to define a constant on that scheme, and on `Run Script` build phase, I want to execute a custom command. I don't have problems with adding a run script phase and execute a command. But I have trouble with the conditional. I'm effectively following this tutorial:

https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#crashreporting-symbolication/iOS

How do I define a variable only one a scheme, and read that variable on custom script in the `if [ ... ]` block?

Answer (score 1):

[There's a difference between Configurations (like "Debug" & "Release") and Schemes](http://www.blackdogfoundry.com/blog/migrating-ios-app-through-multiple-environments/) (which are more broad, specifying the target that's going to be built, the configuration that will be used to build it -- you can select a different configuration for running vs profiling vs archiving, and which tests get run).

So instead of trying to determine the scheme at build time ([there used to be a `SCHEME_NAME` environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8195396/981049), that appears to be gone as of Xcode 5), what you ***should*** do is create a new configuration ([instructions on how to do this can be found here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/BasingBuildConfigurationsonConfigurationFiles.html)) and then you can define any specific environment variables you wish.